# I'm wondering how the Egyptians figured out the false position method in solving their equations?

Tags: mathematical-logic, algebra, ancient-egypt

I'm wondering how the Egyptians figured out the false position method in solving their equations? Is there a good source that can tell me how they thought through this?

Comment: Welcome to HMTSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: If there is an answer, it would be interesting.  But my guess is: there is no way to tell.